# What is the added value of the -T option in GNU cp and mv?

Tags: cp, coreutils

Why do some GNU Coreutils commands have the `-T/--no-target-directory` option? It seems like everything that it does can be achieved using the semantics of the `.` (self dot) in a traditional Unix directory hierarchy.

Considering:

```
cp -rT /this/source dir
```

The `-T` option prevents the copy from creating a `dir/source` subdirectory. Rather `/this/source` is identified with `dir` and the contents are mapped between the trees accordingly. So for instance `/this/source/foo.c` goes to `dir/foo.c` and so on, rather than to `dir/source/foo.c`.

But this can be easily accomplished without the `-T` option using:

```
cp -r /this/source/. dir  # Probably worked fine since dawn of Unix?
```

Semantically, the trailing dot component is copied as a child of `dir`, but of course that "child" already exists (so doesn't have to be created) and is actually `dir` itself, so the effect is that `/this/path` is identified with `dir`.

It works fine if the current directory is the target:

```
cp -r /this/tree/node/. . # node's children go to current dir
```

Is there something you can do **only** with `-T` that can rationalize its existence? (Besides support for operating systems that don't implement the dot directory, a rationale not mentioned in the documentation.)

Does the above dot trick not solve the same race conditions that are mentioned in the GNU Info documentation about `-T`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your `.` trick can only be used when you're copying a directory, not a file. The `-T` option works with both directories and files. If you do:

```
cp srcfile destfile
```

and there's already a directory named `destfile` it will copy to `destfile/srcfile`, which may not be intended. So you use

```
cp -T srcfile destfile
```

and you correctly get the error:

```
cp: cannot overwrite directory `destfile' with non-directory
```

If you tried using the `.` method, the copy would never work:

```
cp: cannot stat `srcfile/.`: Not a directory
```

Comment: The `.` trick *does* work when copying a file, just not when renaming its basename at the same time! `cp /path/to/file /target/dir/.`  If `/target/dir/file` exists and is a directory, you get the same diagnostic!  But you have shown what `-T` does that can't be done without it in one step, without race conditions: copy a file and change its name without it being shunted to a subdirectory.

Comment: That's not the same -- the `.` trick you're talking about is appending `/.` to the **source**.

Answer (score 24):

The problem with `cp`/`mv`/`ln` as they were originally designed is that they're two commands in one (*copy to* and *copy into*).

```
cp A B
```

is either *copy A to B* or *copy A into B* (*copy A to B/A*) depending on whether `B` exists and is a directory or not (and more variations if B is a symlink to a directory).

That's bad because it's ambiguous. So the GNU implementations have added options to work around that.

```
cp -T A B
```

*copies A to B* regardless. If `B` exists and is a directory, that will fail (unless you pass `-r`). In any case, you will not end-up with a `A` file inside `B` when you intended `A` to be copied *to* B.

And:

```
cp -t B A
```

is the *copy into*.

Comment: The original unix philosophy is to assume you know what you do, and will happily allow you to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @Lenne, but here it doesn't give you a way to avoid shooting yourself in the foot. If someone creates a B directory or symlink to some directory just before you run `cp A B` the command will not do what you intended. And doing `[ -e B ] || [ -L B ] || cp A B` still has a race condition which `cp -Tn A B` doesn't have.

Answer (score 6):

The `-T` can provide a failure if a directory incorrectly exists for what should be a destination file:

```
$ mkdir mustbeafile
$ touch afile
$ cp -T afile mustbeafile
cp: cannot overwrite directory `mustbeafile' with non-directory
$ echo $?
1
$ cp afile mustbeafile
$
```

That is, instead of success-on-unexpected-copy-to-a-subdir, a warning and not-good exit status happens, which could then cause a script to abort, and human inspect why there's a directory where there shouldn't be one.

Answer (score 0):

Using a flag is also much clearer, and has less risk of unintended effects, when the command is used in a script instead of manually entered. Patching dots onto paths in a script could end up in all kinds of unexpected mischief.